# Unable to launch app with Firebase Dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have been using firebase dynamic links for awhile now and everything was working fine until suddenly the link no longer launched the app on android. On the web it works fine but on an android device it shows the loading icon and dissapears. What could be the issue... any suggestions please? Have looked at a number of solutions on stackoverflow but none seem to be working in this case... has anything changed with Android? Code is as below

**Intent in the Manifest**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResults" />


        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="latom.page.link"
            />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Targetting**

```
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 33
```